# Appium: Cannot find an element that is visible

Tags: java, android, appium

I am currently trying to automate a login flow. The coding for the happy path works properly. I am now coding for invalid credentials.

My code looks similar to this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Password']").click;
//At this point the button is pressed
Thread.sleep(10000); //Screen with the following item is definitely visible
MobileElement actual = (MobileElement)(new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='Invalid user ID or password. Try again']")))); 
//Note when I print out the xml and use xpathfinder I get 1 response
```

I am getting this response:

```
Am element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that the `getAttribute("content-desc")` is not what appium is looking for. Instead using `getAttribute("name")` will return the desired value(aka content-desc).

Answer (score 0):

You could try fluent wait instead of normal webdriver wait

```
public void waitForElement(final By by,
            int timeInSeconds,WebDriver driver) {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(timeInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(by);
                if (elements.size() > 0) {

                            return true;
                        }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Then make a call

```
waitForElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='Invalid user ID or password. Try again']", 60,driver)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll definitely try that on a different test case. Turns out it was an issue when I used `getAttribute("content-desc")`. As soon as I changed the attribute to name it worked. I was just strange as the inspector was telling me to use "content-desc"